# Access ActiveMQ with reverse proxy enabled

Tags: java, activemq-classic

The goal is to publish/send message into ActiveMQ through Java code inside a secured company network.

I have configured ActiveMQ in an AWS Cloud EC2 machine (console access: IPAddress:8161). Also I can publish the messages using the AWS IPAddress and port number `61616` (IPAddress:61616) through Java code.

But now I need to publish messages from inside a company network. It is secured and can't access the AWS IPAddress directly.

So we create reverse proxy for

```
IPAddress:8161 to activemq-ui.testdemo.com

IPAddress:61616 to activemq-api.testdemo.com
```

Now I can access ActiveMQ console from our company network using **activemq-ui.testdemo.com**. But couldn't access **activemq-api.testdemo.com** through Java code.

**Getting Below Error:**

```
SEVERE: Error Message: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://activemq-api.demo.com. Reason:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
```

Error looks like expecting port number in the URL. But not sure what to pass for this.

Can anyone help me on how to access ActiveMQ API inside corporate network?

Comment: include the code for the producer and consumer seems like ports are not setup correctly

Comment: Do you have the full stack-trace for that error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the port that the client should attempt to connect to on the connection URI as the error is telling you, something like:

```
tcp://activemq-api.demo.com:80
```

The client does not attempt to guess or deduce what the port is you want it to use and so that field is mandatory.